# Can't seem to load font from internal source?

Tags: html, css, fonts

So basically I just wanna use a different font for the 'body'div but I just can't get it to work.. Could someone tell me how to load them from internal files and from an URL, please ? Thanks in advance!

*(So basically I just wanna use a different font for the 'body'div but I just can't get it to work.. Could someone tell me how to load them from internal files and from an URL, please ? Thanks in advance!)*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'zcool_qingke_huangyouregular';
    src: url('fonts/zcool-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/zcool-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: grey;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

ul#horizontal-list {
  list-style: none;
}

ul#horizontal-list li {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: center;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url("img/bg/background1.png");
 background-color: grey;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.body {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'zcool_qingke_huangyouregular';

}

.content {
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border-right: double;
 border-left: double;
 box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8), -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: arial;
 padding-top: 10%;
 padding-bottom: 10%;
 padding-left: 5%;
 padding-right: 5%;
}

.social {
 margin: auto;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}


.me {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 3%;
 height: 100%;
}



.footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#copyright {
 display: table;
}

#cpy{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
  <meta name="description" content="My Personal Portfolio">
  <title>John's Work</title>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="navbar">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>


  <div class="header">
 <!-- Can stay empty -->
  </div>

  <div class="body">
  <div class="content">
  
Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text Lorem Ipsum Text
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="footer" id="copyright" style="text-align:center">
    <div id="cpy">&copy;  (2019)</div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) declaration looks correct. If by "internal source" you mean files found under a `fonts` directory relative to your css. If you wanted to use a font file local to the user's machine you could use the `local()` function instead of the `src()` function (or better yet use both together).

The issue seems to be that you only call this custom font on the [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) of `.body` however, and that class name isn't used. If you meant to target your `<body>` element then you want to use the `body` [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org) instead.

Comment: Thanks! I think I confused something, I wanted to say 'div content' instead of 'div body' .. I want to use the different font in the div 'çontent'

Comment: Yes, then you would want to use the `font-family: 'zcool_qingke_huangyouregular';` attribute on the `.content` class.